# .gitattributes file not converting line endings

Tags: git, vim, centos, phpstorm

I have created a .gitattributes file in the root dir of my git install (CentOS). I  have created test files in PHPStorm via a samba share connection and specifically set the line endings to CRLF. I add and commit the test file, expecting the file to have the line endings changed to LF, but when I check the file in vim it says: [noeol][dos] next to the file name when I open the file. It seems like the .gitattributes file is not converting to LF... am I incorrect? I am fairly sure I have the attributes set up properly (see below). Am I doing something wrong?

```
# Set the default behavior, in case core.autocrlf is not set
* text=auto

# Explicitly declare text files you want to always be normalized and  converted to native line endings
*.htm text
*.html text
*.tpl text
*.css text
*.js text
*.php text
*.xml text
*.txt text
*.ini text
*.inc text
*.bak text
*.pm text
*.cgi text
.htaccess text

# Denote all files that are truely binary and should not be modified
*.png binary
*.jpg binary
*.jpeg binary
*.gif binary
*.ico binary
*.mov binary
*.mp4 binary
*.mp3 binary
*.flv binary
*.fla binary
*.swf binary
*.gz binary
*.zip binary
*.7z binary
*.ttf binary
```

Comment: Where do you have that attributes file exactly? What do you have the `eol` attribute and `core.eol` git config setting set to?

Comment: The file is in the same dir as the .git folder. - and the core.eol attribute is not set at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git conversions happen to the destination of whatever operation you're performing, and you can have different ones on the way into and out of the repo.  Here you're telling it to convert text eol's both ways but haven't actually pulled any content from the repo yet.  Do a `git reset --hard` to force a refresh of your current worktree from the committed content using any new filters/attributes.
Since `git 2.16` you can also use

```
git add --renormalize .
```

It might be a bit counterintuitive that `text` attribute processing governs what happens on the way into the repo, and `core.eol` governs what happens on the way out:

> **text**
>   This attribute enables and controls end-of-line normalization. When a text file is normalized, its line endings are converted to LF *in the repository*. To control what line ending style is used in the working directory, use the eol attribute for a single file and the core.eol configuration variable for all text files.

Comment: I did that initially to get all existing files to have LF and purge all the CRLFs and that worked - but I had the core.eol set at that time as well. I am trying to do this without the core.eol specifically set to the repo can get deployed and still work if someone forgets to set the core.eol setting.

Comment: I was going by the .gitattribute man page which stated: Set to string value "auto"

    When text is set to "auto", the path is marked for automatic end-of-line normalization. If git decides that the content is text, its line endings are normalized to LF on checkin.

Comment: It's "on checkin" that matters here.  `core.eol` is what governs the checkout behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, it's a bit confusing as to how things are getting handled. I just assumed that once the endings were modified on check in, that would stay modified that way. All in all, I guess having the core.eol set isn't a big deal.

Comment: The endings do stay that way in the repository, you set the repo up to convert to lf on checkin, it did that. You've also left it set for native line endings on checkout, but you have to actually do the checkout with those settings.